# How can update the UI of an In App purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, storekit

I have some doubts using In app purchase. AFAIK only the first In app purchase is approved along with the binary. This is my current state,
I have my app already in AppStore with one weekly subscription.

Now I wonder if the following roadmap is possible:

- Update the current IAP UI
- Send to apple Apple Review more Weekly and Monthly subscriptions plans(some of them just change the introductory price)
- My backend will decide which plan will showed to the user.

My problem now is I'm not able to update my current approved IAP, I modify the name, description and screenshot but when I save the changes the IAP is still Approved. Is it possible update a approved IAP? what about if I want to change the background?

On the other hand, I have another IAP waiting for review the last 5 days. Is it normal? Have I to send along with the binary to the app store review?

Comment: Once an IAP has been approved all you can do is change its price.  The IAP screenshot is never seen by the user, only by the review team, so once it is approved there is no need to change the screenshot. You would need to submit a new binary to support the new IAP anyway (assuming you didn't build your initial binary to support the planned IAP identifiers)

Comment: @Paulw11 my plan is change the IAP from backend, in order to avoid submit a new binary every time. Is it posible?

Comment: Yes, once your first IAP is approved you can add new products without submitting a new binary. Pro tip: wait 24hrs after your new products become 'Approved' before showing them to users since sometimes it takes a while for them to propagate throughout the store.